# When creating flexible terraform module to customize optional parameters

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to put couple of resources in a terrafrom module. of this one of the resources is `aws_ecs_service` has some optional arguments which I may or may not need and I would like pass the values when calling the modules.

For example consider `ordered_placement_strategy` argument. A service could have a single or multiple ordered_placement_strategy. Some services may or may not have `placement_constraints`. How can I write flexible generic module for aws_ecs_service.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "mongo" {
  name            = "mongodb"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.foo.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.mongo.arn
  desired_count   = 3
  iam_role        = aws_iam_role.foo.arn
  depends_on      = [aws_iam_role_policy.foo]

  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "binpack"
    field = "cpu"
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.foo.arn
    container_name   = "mongo"
    container_port   = 8080
  }

  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-west-2a, us-west-2b]"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a solid use-case for [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html) + [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html).

It will help if you already know the task placement strategies that should be supported in the module. You can expose an input variable to the end-users and use that to create the service accordingly.

For example: Let's say, we want to support two kind of services:

- simple
- complex

I would first define an input variable with validation like this, to avoid the unknowns:

```
variable "ecs_service_type" {
  type        = string
  description = "What kind of service is this?"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(simple|complex)$", var.ecs_service_type))
    error_message = "The service type must be in (simple|complex)."
  }
}
```

You can define the supported task placement strategies and constraints using local values like this:

```
locals {
  ordered_placement_strategy = {
    simple = [
      {
        "field" : "instanceId",
        "type" : "spread"
      }
    ]
    complex = [
      {
        type  = "spread"
        field = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
      },
      {
        type  = "spread"
        field = "instanceId"
      }
    ]
  }

  placement_constraints = {
    simple = []

    complex = [
      {
        type = "distinctInstance"
      }
    ]
  }

}
```

And, in the end, create the service accordingly using dynamic blocks:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  ...
  ...

  dynamic "ordered_placement_strategy" {
    for_each = local.ordered_placement_strategy[var.ecs_service_type]

    content {
      type  = ordered_placement_strategy.value.type
      field = ordered_placement_strategy.value.field
    }
  }

  dynamic "placement_constraints" {
    for_each = local.placement_constraints[var.ecs_service_type]

    content {
      type = placement_constraints.value.type
    }
  }
}
```

PS: This specific piece of code is not tested but I have used similar approaches. Let me know if you need help with anything.

Comment: Thanks this is helpfull but two questions. do we need to use local or can we use variable? This is so that can then have all values in my .tfvars. Second I do not understand this  local.placement_constraints[var.ecs_service_type]. In the local definition there is no reference to ecs_service_type.

Comment: @kumar - So, there are many ways to go about it. I preferred locals for this use-case as I wanted to simplify the decision making for end-users. 

More on this topic: 
- https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/locals
- https://medium.com/@pavloosadchyi/terraform-patterns-and-tricks-i-use-every-day-117861531173


You can check these publicly available ecs modules and decide which approach suits your needs:
- https://github.com/infrablocks/terraform-aws-ecs-service
- https://github.com/trussworks/terraform-aws-ecs-service